# How to trigger a sampling oscilloscope on a PAM-5 signal

Tags: oscilloscope, measurement, ethernet

I am trying to acquire an eye diagram on a Gigabit Ethernet (PAM-5) signal, measuring differentially over pair 1. I am using a Tektronix DSA 71254c.

I have not been able to successfully configure the trigger of the oscilloscope to trigger on the signal so that it produces an eye diagram, using only the differential signal and the oscilloscope without any external clock signal, clock recovery or other hardware.

Is it possible to do this, or do I need additional signals or hardware?

Comment: If the scope supports it, yes you can. But neither does every scope have this capability, nor are they even fast enough to see such signals.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I'm using an expensive DSA with 100GS/s 12.5GHz, so it's got the specs. I'm just not sure of which type of trigger to use...

Comment: I am a little bit surprised that someone lets you work with such equipment without proper training. Anyways, all scopes have different triggers, depending on make, model and purchased options. There is no single catch it all solution to do this. Since you seem to have a problem with telling up front what it is, all I can suggest to you is look at some youtube videos where they do it and try to replicate.

Comment: Me too... Though I was trained to do PAM-2 and -3 signal eye diagrams on this piece, but the 5 levels complicate things...
I've searched YouTube for 30 minutes with no result.
Well one way would of course be to trigger on an external clock signal.

Comment: maybe be more creative with search terms? searching for "gigabit ethernet oscilloscope" lead me to at least a few promising hits, and descriptions show that keysight scopes seem to have hardware for pam-n clock recovery and just somewhere something in the menus for that.

Comment: This manual http://www.tek.com/dl/55W_17291_6_0.pdf shows 8b/10b triggers that include gigabit Ethernet (see page 27). Whether that does PAM-5 I do not know, but you might try.

Answer (score 1):

Hm... Observing (measuring) the 1000BASE-T physical waveforms is not so simple (and obvious) as with 10BASE-T and 100BASE-TX. The difficult is from the fact that the 1000BASE-T PHY uses bidirectional (and one-source synchronous) transmission at each of the fours pairs being employed.

Therefore, to test a signal of the PHY, you need:

- configure the PHY to a special, test mode when it will generate a known waveform on a pair, needing no link partner: there are **five IEEE 802.3ab test modes** described in IEEE Std 802.3, Section 40.6.1.1.2, one/some of them may be of your interest;
- if your PHY IC support the test trigger(s) outputs on its pin(s), e.g. like National Semiconductor DP83865 does, you may use such a trigger output to synchronize your oscilloscope with the test waveform you selected in the PHY; or
- if your PHY IC does not support the test triggers, your need use a native means of the oscilloscope, but imo it is not problem now (with known, one-directional waveform) because the test waveforms are single-sourced and generated repeatedly and/or continuously.

Also one thing to remain is that to do all these things, you need a configuration access to the PHY under test, e.g. MDIO/MDC or something else to control the PHY registers to reach the necessary behavior on the wire.